# How to setup the CLASSPATH to load resources relative to the jar file?

Tags: java, classpath

I have some jar files that need to read files at startup. These files are located in directories next the jar files. This is how my directory listing looks like:

```
code.jar
config/
       confifile.cfg
```

Then, in a command line prompt, I set the classpath as:

```
set CLASSPATH=./ext/*;./*
```

Then I run the program but it keeps complaining that it cannot find the "configfile.cfg".

> /config/configfile.cfg file not found!

This error comes from this code:

```
try {
    r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader((String)botinfilename));
    fileName=(String)botinfilename;
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println(botinfilename + " is not found");
}
```

I noticed it works if I put the /config directory inside the jar file. But if I remove it and put it next to the jar it does not find the config file.

Is there some java setting trick to make this work?

### EDIT 1:

I launch my program like this:

> java StartProgram

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path to see if that works when the config file is outside the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it short, I just added the "-cp" JVM option. My problem was I need to add the root directory (where my jars and resources are located) to my classpath. Previously I had just added the jars with the * wildcard.

```
java -cp PATH_ROOT_DIR/;PATH_TO_ROOT_DIR/*;PATH_TO_ROOT_DIR/ext/* StartProgram
```

or you can set the class path

```
set CLASSPATH=./;./ext/*;./*
```